# CI Session doesn't work properly in some browsers

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have bumped with weird problem and have no clue what happens and what is wrong. Website built in on CI platform. My CI uses table sessions and here is config

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'pi_session'.md5(date('mdY'));
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 7200;
```

It worked well all the time but recently I suddenly couldn't login into admin area in FF. But all work well on localhost sever in the same browser. In Chrome I can login from both remote and localhost. But other guy told me that he can login in FF but can't in Chrome. 
When I load login page on remote server in FF it creates 2 records in the `ci_sessions` table instead of one, the same action in Chrome creates 1 record only and login option work well.

```
61a182973989856167cfa945519705ed    12.68.11.93     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36   1489174945  
66fc8c300986a83eb58514a6aafef360    12.68.11.93     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0   1489174908  
bbc0c642bd0049d3bc4d663ea94273db 12.68.11.93    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0   1489174907
```

The first record is when I opened page in chrome, 2-3 I opened page in FF. What a?

Comment: What version of CI are you running? If it is CI2 the sessions do not work reliably. Broken beyond repair. CI3 sessions work perfectly and sessions were completely rewritten in CI3. CI2 is no longer supported and has not been for some time.

Comment: I have updated to 3 still the same :(

Comment: What error message do you get (php error or generated error message) on a failed login attempt?

Comment: @PaulD no error. It seems related to a browser. Every page reload generate new session_id in FF but in Chrome it works correctly. Seems like browser or maybe DDos filter blocking session. But no errors.

Comment: put sess_match_useragent to FALSE